# Can we remove some of the limitations to editing posts?

Tags: feature-request

This may be the wrong place to ask this question; I have no idea whether this is a workplace.SE or a generic SE problem. Feel free to migrate accordingly.

A recent workplace.SE post contains a typographic error: a single word has a single spurious letter. The rest of the post is quite well-written, so nothing else obvious is to be corrected here. So in the last few minutes of my lunch break, I go and fix this typo. The following error message appears:

[image: Edits must be at least 6 characters; your edit summary must be at least 10 characters]

Now, I can circumvent the "edit summary" error message by spelling out "typographic error" or actually mentioning the word that I fixed (although I don't see the point of that; the information is available elsewhere in the edit, so this is just hoop jumping for the sake of hoop jumping), but the "Edits must be at least 6 characters" error message makes me just leave the website without correcting the error.

As of now, the error is still present in the post. Surely that cannot be the intended consequence of this limitation. Can we scrap it?

Comment: It's a generic topic that's been discussed, some would say ad nauseam, over on main meta. Recommend you start from [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520) and the linked questions.

Comment: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: <!-- --> <!-- -->

Comment: A tiny, single-character typographical error isn't worth fixing.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sometimes it is, especially for non English speakers here who have more trouble picking up the correct meaning through context. 'Sing' vrs 'sign', 'by' vrs 'buy' etc,..... the people who can do them don't need them approved, so I reckon it's fine even if they just add a fullstop. It doesn't interfere with anyone else and improves aesthetics.

Comment: @Kilisi - we'll have to agree to disagree on that I guess.

Comment: When you have enough rep (it's 2k; for the entire list see the privileges page) you can edit with no restrictions. Until then, simply post a comment to the OP pointing out the typo, it usually works and if the OP doesn't pick up on it someone else will.

Comment: What I've yet to understand is why am I trusted to edit on three Stack Exchange sites but not network wide. Typos, misspellings, and poor formatting happen on any site,  regardless of the site's topic. Why should an edit by a trusted user still have to be approved by users who may have significantly fewer years of experience?

Comment: @Mari-LouA it's a privilege, it needs to be earned here, I don't think privileges earned elsewhere should count. Just because I'm an upstanding respectable member here, doesn't mean I'm not a troublesome nutcase elsewhere. It's the internet.

Answer (score 4):

We can't change this it's system wide. I don't see it as a problem, as it's in there by design. But the 6 character limit does go away as you progress in rep. I'm not sure at what stage but I can make single character edits.

The 10 character limit to the edit summary doesn't. But if you're pedantic enough to fix a single character it shouldn't be onerous to type 'Fixed spelling' or 'Fixed typo.' or something like that.

'Fix typo' is itself a typing error in terms of what is meant.

Comment: Mods can make single character edits.  I don't believe the six-character limit goes away for other users, irrespective of rep.

Comment: I am not a moderator and I can make single character edits. I usually only do it in the first few hours of a question or answer to limit the bumping impact.

Comment: Once you have earned 2k edits are immediately approved, there's no need for it to enter the suggested edit review queue, which in my experience, on TWP can take as long as a day.

Comment: Just thought you might be interested to hear that SE has recently announced accepted answers on SO will no longer be pinned at the top of the page. If you are and others are interested in adopting the same change for TWP, you have until September 18.   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers P.S I'm presuming that this proposal has not been communicated to moderators across the network.

Comment: @Mari-LouA other mods might be interested. Doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: It seems you're not interested in taking this any further but you should because there's a chance, however slim, it might be implemented across the network.

Comment: @Mari-LouA que sera sera